# Use Zapier to check new entries in typeform agains existing contacts in teamleader

Tags: zapier, typeform, teamleader

I am using typeform to generate leads for my company through a landing page and it asks for a phone number. I am using this phone number to call them and when they pick up I add them to my teamleader CRM system. However, this is very inefficient because I have to add all those leads to Teamleader manually.

I have created some zaps through Zapier to automatically generate contacts in Teamleader when a new Typeform entry is submitted, however, some people fill in the form more than once. Also, I am using more than one typeform and some people fill in different forms with the same data. Therefore, I was wondering whether it is possible to have Zapier check whether a certain phone number is already in my teamleader database, and only create a contact when this particular phone number does not yet exist.

I have already tried using a filter, but I noticed that Zapier can only filter typeform contacts based on their ID, which is not helpful.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the official APIs of Teamleader https://developer.teamleader.eu/#/reference/crm/contacts/contacts.list I think you can search users by their number,name or email.

You can also load all your data into airtable and use it as a lookup in zapier. Alternatively you can request this feature from teamleader on their Zapier app.

Comment: I think you can use: https://developer.teamleader.eu/#/reference/crm/contacts/contacts.list and filter using the email address.